# Ansible - remove empty elements from the list

Tags: list, ansible, element

I have an ansible output from which I want to remove all empty (none) elements for a specific attribute. Here is the example list:

```yaml
"resources": [
    {
        "id": "9c40900909",
        "name": "some_name1"
    },
    {
        "id": "pc4b09090"
    },
    {
        "id": "8lknkkn45"
    },
    {
        "id": "9df40900909",
        "name": "some_name2"
    }
]
```

Here is how I reduced the list to be just "resources" with attribute "name":

```yaml
- set_fact:
    resources_names: "{{ output.resources | map(attribute='name') }}"
```

Problem with that is that I get the elements that does not have any value for the name. These are "AnsibleUndefined" in the following output:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: resources_names list is "{{ resources_names }}"
```

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => {
   "msg": "resources_names list is \"['some_name1', AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined, 'some_name2']\""
}
```

I tried to remove it with reject and regexp but that's not working.

```yaml
- set_fact:
    list2: "{{ resources_names | reject('match', '^$') | list }}"
```

Same with this one:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    resources_names: "{{ output.resources | map(attribute='name') | rejectattr('name', 'none') }}"
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    resources: [
        {
            "id": "9c40900909",
            "name": "some_name1"
        },
        {
            "id": "pc4b09090"
        },
        {
            "id": "8lknkkn45"
        },
        {
            "id": "9df40900909",
            "name": "some_name2"
        }
    ]

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ resources | selectattr('name', 'defined') | map(attribute='name') }}"
```

which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook /tmp/play.yml 
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "some_name1",
        "some_name2"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

*Note for your next question: please make sure you double check your examples and paste valid json/yaml data in your question. Thanks*

Comment: Both solutions works, thanks! @Zeitounator, will do, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the filter *json_query*. This filter ignores missing attributes

```yaml
resources_names: "{{ output.resources|json_query('[].name') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
resources_names:
  - some_name1
  - some_name2
```